# ExtJS 7 Modern : Retrieve grid selected rows

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I have a grid with checkbox selection to allow multiple rows selection.

```js
Ext.define("app.view.grid.MyGrid", {
  extend: "Ext.grid.Grid",
  xtype: "app.MyGrid",

  viewModel: "Grid",

  selectable: {
    rows: true,
    checkbox: true,
  },
```

But now, how can I get all the selected rows? If I use `grid.getSelection()`, it only shows the latest selected row. I saw many answers using `grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()` but this works on Classic toolkit, I am using `7.4 Modern`.

If I try, it gives me `getSelectionModel() is not a function` and this method is not available anymore : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html#event-select

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `grid.getSelections()`, in modern toolkit it should return an array with the selected items.

Comment: It works! Damn, I can't believe it was so easy. Could you tell me how you found this? I took a look at the API doc but there is no "getSelectionS()" plural method listed, only "getSelection()" in singular. Thanks

Comment: If you search for `getSelection` in modern toolkit documentation, not on the first page, but later you will see two classes with `getSelections`:  `Ext.dataview.selection.Model` and `Ext.mixin.Selectable`. One of these is used in grid (I don't know which), but somehow it is missing from the grid's documentation.

Comment: I don't see the `Ext.mixin.Selectable` in the `Grid` mixins and inherited mixins list, so unless the doc is incomplete, I think it relies on `Ext.dataview.selection.Model`. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: You are welcome, I think it is a documentation problem.